# Python APscheduler and returning filepath of most recent csv in directory

Tags: python, csv, pandas, apscheduler

I am trying to get the below code to write files to the specified folder with no luck. I think the error is with the imported 'glob' package/function because similar code works for other files, but I'm not sure. Note also that I'm not getting any errors on the in-between 'do stuff' code so I don't think that's an issue.

```
#Import Stuff
import pandas as pd
import os
#Import apscheduler and related packages
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

def process_ZN_ES_comb_LL_15M_csv(path_to_csv):
    # Open ZN_ES_comb and customize


    filename2 = max(glob.iglob("C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\ZN_ES\ZN_ES_15M\CSV\Beta\*.csv"))
    ZN_ES_comb_LL_15M = pd.read_csv(filename2)
    #Do stuff, no errors given

#Send to csv automatically
    ZN_ES_comb_LL_15M.to_csv(path_to_csv.replace('.csv', '_modified_{timestamp}.csv').format(
        timestamp=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")), index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path_to_csv = "C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\ZN_ES\ZN_ES_15M\CSV\Lead_Lag\ZN_ES_comb_LL_15M.csv"
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()
    scheduler.add_job(func=process_ZN_ES_comb_LL_15M_csv,
                      args=[path_to_csv],
                      trigger=IntervalTrigger(seconds=60))
    # Wait for 7 seconds so that scheduler can call process_csv 3 times
    time.sleep(7)
```

Essentially I'm having apscheduler automatically write the file to the folder shown below, but nothing is showing up. Further, I have to identify a file using 'glob' package from another folder in order to build on that file in the #do stuff lines. That's why I think there's some issue with the filename2 line but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try use double quotes `"` for your filename2 line. The thing that is jumping out at me is the whitespace in the file path "Daily Tasks" and using double quotes can solve this issue.

Comment: Hey, no such luck. I have another file that's running well in the same manner in "Daily Tasks"...only it doesn't reference the most recent csv file in a folder but does so explicitly...which is why I think the issue is with the 'glob' line but not sure. edit: I also change to double brackets, updated.